# Access Query Planned vs Realised

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created 2 Queries in Access and now I want to combine them.

1 of them returns sample data (Planned) :

| EmployeId | TrainingId | Planned Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 |

Other returns sample data (Completed) :

| EmployeId | TrainingId | Completed Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |

The required Result from the 3rd query is  :

| EmployeId | TrainingId | Planned Hours | Completed Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 |  | 10 |

I created a UNION ALL query like below but this return extra rows :

```
SELECT *
    FROM [Qry-Completed]
        LEFT JOIN [Qry-Planned]
        ON [Qry-Completed].TrainingId = [Qry-Planned].TrainingId AND 
              [Qry-Completed].EmployeId  = [Qry-Planned].EmployeId 
UNION ALL SELECT *
    FROM [Qry-Completed]
        RIGHT JOIN [Qry-Planned]
        ON [Qry-Completed].TrainingId = [Qry-Planned].TrainingId AND
             [Qry-Completed].EmployeId  = [Qry-Planned].EmployeId ;
```

How can I join these 2 queries to get the desired result?

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where a full outer join actually makes sense. Edit: Nevermind. But I'll keep my shame visible in case others try. Access apparently doesn't support full outer joins.

Comment: @nbk How does a full outer join not make sense? This is the exact thing they are meant for, where you have two sets of disjoint keys and you want all keys in the output without duplication. Just a full outer join on EmployeeID and TrainingID with some coalesces is what I'd do working with any real DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for SQL Server, but that same strategy should hold in Access.

This takes advantage of the fact that UNION will remove duplicates. So it'll get rid of the extra rows except for the orphans in either direction.

https://dbfiddle.uk/Ch9Y7vkd

```
create table planned 
  (
    employee_id integer,
    training_id integer,
    planned_hours integer
  );

create table actual
  (
    employee_id integer,
    training_id integer,
    completed_hours integer

  );

insert into planned values 
  (1,1,5),
  (1,2,6),
  (1,3,7);

insert into actual values 
  (1,2,6),
  (1,3,8),
  (1,4,10);

select p.employee_id,
       p.training_id,
       p.planned_hours,
       a.completed_hours
  from planned p
  left
  join actual a
    on p.employee_id = a.employee_id
   and p.training_id = a.training_id
 union
select a.employee_id,
       a.training_id,
       p.planned_hours,
       a.completed_hours
  from actual a
  left
  join planned p
    on p.employee_id = a.employee_id
   and p.training_id = a.training_id
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer yet, since MS Access does not support `common table` or `outer join`,

Answer (score 1):

I would create a middle table - or a full-select - containing all possible distinct combinations of employee id and training id from both `planned` and `completed`:

```
WITH
alltrainings AS (
  SELECT
    employeeid
  , trainingid
  FROM planned
  UNION SELECT
    employeeid
  , trainingid
  FROM completed
)
SELECT
  a.employeeid
, a.trainingid
, planned_hours
, completed_hours 
FROM alltrainings a
LEFT JOIN planned p
  ON a.employeeid=p.employeeid AND a.trainingid=p.trainingid
LEFT JOIN completed c
  ON a.employeeid=c.employeeid AND a.trainingid=c.trainingid
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| employeeid | trainingid | planned_hours | completed_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | (null) |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 | (null) | 10 |

Comment: There is no CTE in MsAccess, but if the WITH table is substituted by a subquery this would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use FULL OUTER JOIN as follows:

```
select COALESCE(p.employeeId, a.employeeId) as employeeId,
       COALESCE(p.trainingId, a.trainingId) as trainingId,
       p.planned as planned,
       a.completed
  from planned p
  FULL OUTER JOIN actual a
    on a.employeeId = p.employeeId
   and a.trainingId = p.trainingId
```